# redirect if user directly enters page name in URL

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have to redirect page if the user entered page name in URL. I have two pages called as index.php and next.php

In index.php page there is a link called `<a href="next.php">Click here</a>`. If i clicked on link then page is redirecting on next.php properly.

Now the issue is if any user directly entered next.php on URL then the page should be redirected on index.php page. That means the user will not able to access directly next.php

Comment: Check the referer in `next.php`?

Comment: Referrer is unreliable. Use a session.

Answer (score 0):

generally you want to check the user (account, session ID) against a server to prevent this kind of unwanted routing.

This can be done for example by wrapping entire pages (routes) in a custom component / function that checks permissions / session ID / etc. In the case the user doesn't *belong* on the page (`next.php` in your case), reroute him back or to some sort of a home page.

This technique is called **route protection**. Check [this article](https://vegibit.com/how-to-protect-specific-routes-with-middleware/) that talks about the issue.